# I can not use any functions in Format cells menue

Tags: microsoft-excel

I get warning " Your entry cannot be used. An integer or decimal number may be requiered".
This warning shows up in all menues.

Comment: add some images showing what you are doing, and the problem you are having

Comment: Please [edit] your post & share Screen shot with us,,,also what you have tried so far,,, I think that you are struggling with Iteration!! Do this ,, Hit  `File` tab / `Options`
Select `Formula` to `set calculation` either `Automatic/Manual` also the number of `Iterations and maximum change (ie .001)` ☺

Answer (score 0):

1. The conflict of format settings between Excel and Windows may cause this issue.

You may go to `Control Panel > Clock and Region > Region > Format`, modify the settings that you need, other formats like Numbers, Currency, time or Date, please click Additional settings.

Or you could go to `File in Excel > Options > Advanced`, uncheck "**Use system separators**" to check this issue.

2. Although the probability caused by the margin is not large, but if you have changed the margins, please also check whether the values are too small in Custom Margins.